# Apache Spark write takes hours

Tags: apache-spark, cassandra, apache-spark-sql, spark-cassandra-connector

I have a spark job which makes a right join based on two tables, the reading and joining is pretty fast but when try to insert join resuls to cassandra db it is so slow. It takes more than 30 minutes to insert 1000 rows, takes 3 minutes to insert 9 rows record. Please see my configuration below. we have 3 cassandra and spark node and spark is installed for all nodes. I'm pretty new with  Spark and cant understand what is wrong. ı can insert same sized data with dse driver less than 1 second (more than 2000 rows). I appreciate your time and help!!

Spark submit :

```
"dse -u " + username + " -p " + password + " spark-submit --class com.SparkJoin --executor-memory=20G  " +
                "SparkJoinJob-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar " + filterMap.toString() + "
```

Spark core version : 2.7.2

spark-cassandra-connector_2.11 : 2.3.1

spark-sql_2.11 : 2.3.1

Spark Conf

```
  SparkConf conf = new SparkConf(true).setAppName("Appname");
    conf.set("spark.cassandra.connection.host", host);
    conf.set("spark.cassandra.auth.username", username);
    conf.set("spark.cassandra.auth.password", password);

    conf.set("spark.network.timeout", "600s");
    conf.set("spark.cassandra.connection.keep_alive_ms", "25000");
    conf.set("spark.cassandra.connection.timeout_ms", "5000000");
    conf.set("spark.sql.broadcastTimeout", "5000000");
    SparkContext sc = new SparkContext(conf);

    SparkSession sparkSession = SparkSession.builder().sparkContext(sc).getOrCreate();
    SQLContext sqlContext = sparkSession.sqlContext();

    sqlContext.setConf("spark.cassandra.connection.host", host);
    sqlContext.setConf("spark.cassandra.auth.username", username);
    sqlContext.setConf("spark.cassandra.auth.password", password);
    sqlContext.setConf("spark.network.timeout", "600s");
    sqlContext.setConf("spark.cassandra.connection.keep_alive_ms", "2500000");
    sqlContext.setConf("spark.cassandra.connection.timeout_ms", "5000000");
    sqlContext.setConf("spark.sql.broadcastTimeout", "5000000");
    sqlContext.setConf("spark.executor.heartbeatInterval", "5000000");
    sqlContext.setConf("spark.sql.crossJoin.enabled", "true");
```

Left and Right Table fetch;

```
  Dataset<Row> resultsFrame = sqlContext.sql("select * from table where conditions");
return resultsFrame.map((MapFunction<Row, JavaObject>) row -> {
// some operations here

                return obj;
            }, Encoders.bean(JavaObject.class)
    );
```

Join

```
   Dataset<Row> result = RigtTableJavaRDD.join(LeftTableJavaRDD,
            (LeftTableJavaRDD.col("col1").minus(RigtTableJavaRDD.col("col2"))).
                    between(new BigDecimal("0").subtract(twoHundredMilliseconds), new BigDecimal("0").add(twoHundredMilliseconds))
                    .and(LeftTableJavaRDD.col("col5").equalTo(RigtTableJavaRDD.col("col6")))
            , "right");
```

Insert Result

```
  CassandraJavaUtil.javaFunctions(resultRDD.javaRDD()).
            writerBuilder("keyspace", "table", CassandraJavaUtil.mapToRow(JavaObject.class)).
            saveToCassandra();
```

Comment: Did you find any useful logs in spark's executor nodes?

Comment: what version of DSE are you using? What `result.explain()` prints? If you're using Datasets - why you're using join on RDDs instead of joins of Datasets?